# When I run an MPI program, what is the meaning of this ? "mpirun noticed that the job aborted..."

Tags: c++, mpi, openmpi

When I run my code I get the following message:

> mpirun noticed that the job aborted, but has no info as to the process that caused that situation

My MPI code runs properly and gives expected output, but in the end I see this message. **What does this mean and how do I get rid of it ?**
I am implementing an MPI reducer for this. I have a feeling that it has nothing to do with my code as such.

Comment: Are you missing a `return 0;` statement at the end of your `main()` function or returning a non-zero exit code?